# how to fetch result from asynctask into mainactivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a translater app and all code is working fine but at the last part my app is crashed while fetching the result from asynctask into mainactivity,what I'm doing wrong here

```
enter code here
MainActivity.java
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
                texttotranslate = et.getText().toString();
                Log.d("text:", "" + texttotranslate);

                OkhttpHandler myTask = new OkhttpHandler(new AsyncResponse(){

                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String output)
                        {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            Log.d("Response from asynctask", (String) output);
                            t.setText((String)output);
                        }


                    });    
                myTask.execute(texttotranslate, lang_pair);

            }
        });
```

I already created an interface AsyncResponse and added a method processFinish(String output) into it

```
enter code here
OkHttpHandler.java
 public class OkhttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> 
 {
String res;
String transres;
String finalres;
public AsyncResponse delegate;

public OkhttpHandler(AsyncResponse delegate)
{
  this.delegate = delegate; 
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String[] values)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String texttotranslate = values[0];
    String lang_pair = values[1];
    String key = "my-key";
    String url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + key
        + "&text=" + texttotranslate + "&lang=" + lang_pair;

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

    try
    {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        res = response.body().string();     
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (res != null)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(res);
            transres = jsonobj.getString("text");
            String f = transres.replace("[", "");
            String s = f.replace("]", "");
            finalres = s.replace("\"", "");
            Log.d("final result", "" + finalres);   
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return finalres;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    delegate.processFinish(result);
    Log.d("result:", "" + result);
}

}
```

My app is crashed while launching and there is no any error showing in my logcat.

Comment: If you cant get error from logcat, try debugging the app with possible debug points.

Comment: Tried still no use, i am using AIDE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accidentally deleted okio library from libs folder that's why my app was crashing, so now it's solved.
So if anyone using okhttp library then add okio library too.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace my-key with your yandex API_KEY

```
String key = "my-key";
```

Everything else is fine I tried your code

https://github.com/naveendew/yandex_translate_example

Comment: I just edit that for posting here, i used my yandex api key there

Comment: please check project https://github.com/naveendew/yandex_translate_example
with api_key

Comment: I had deleted okio library, that was the problem.